# How to make Picker with ObservedObject and NSManagedObject?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

In my view I define a few ObservedObjects. ShoppingItems and Packages are NSManagedObject subclasses.

```
    @ObservedObject var shoppingListData: ShoppingListData
    @ObservedObject var shoppingItem: ShoppingItems
    @ObservedObject var package: Packages

    init(thisData: ShoppingListData, formShoppingItem: ShoppingItems, formPackage: Packages?) {
        shoppingListData = thisData
        shoppingItem = formShoppingItem

        if let fp = formPackage {
            package = fp
        } else if let fp = formShoppingItem.minStorePackage {
            package = fp
        } else {
            let newPackage = Packages(context: thisData.dataStack.moc)
            newPackage.myShoppingItem = formShoppingItem
            newPackage.myStore = thisData.dataStack.currentReceipt.myStore!
            package = newPackage
        }
    }
```

In my body I have a picker.

```
 Picker(selection: $package, label: Text("Store Packages")) {
     ForEach(shoppingItem.storePackages, id: \.uuidKey) { pkg in
         Text(pkg.brandName).tag(pkg.uuidKey)         
     }
 }
```

The picker will display the other packages, but it does not change the package variable from the old package to the newly selected package. Is there some SwiftUI restriction against changing which instance an @ObservedObject points to after the view is initialized?

Comment: Need to see more of your classes/structs (`ShoppingListData`, `ShoppingItems`, `Packages`) before I can help.